# How can I make ruby-lint not report false-positives on undefined constants?

Tags: ruby, lint

I'm trying to use ruby-lint, but have some false positive error.

Versions:

```
=$ ruby --version
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

=$ ruby-lint --version
warning: parser/current is loading parser/ruby23, which recognizes
warning: 2.3.7-compliant syntax, but you are running 2.3.3.
warning: please see https://github.com/whitequark/parser#compatibility-with-ruby-mri.
ruby-lint v2.3.1 on ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

I have a script that does:

```
require 'syslog'
```

and later on uses Syslog::LOG_* constants.

It works, and is all OK, but ruby-lint reports these as errors:

```
=$ ruby-lint pg_terminator.rb
...
test.rb: error: line 23, column 23: undefined constant Syslog::LOG_AUTHPRIV
test.rb: error: line 23, column 23: undefined constant Syslog
test.rb: error: line 24, column 23: undefined constant Syslog::LOG_AUTH
```

and so on.

Is there any way to "explain" to ruby-lint that required modules have some visible constants/classes?

Comment: Looks like a flaw in the (abandoned) library's design. [The standard library constants were auto-generated by Rubinius 2.2.3, and are stored here](https://github.com/YorickPeterse/ruby-lint/tree/87842ae295c2283d8e02d951781189486a7cc970/lib/ruby-lint/definitions/core). Assuming those definitions are comprehensive (I didn't bother checking), my guess is that Rubinius 2.2.3 simply didn't have a `Syslog` class, whereas MRI `2.3.3` does?

Comment: Regardless, the library seems quite flawed to me. For example, you can mention `DateTime` in your code and ruby-lint [won't complain](https://github.com/YorickPeterse/ruby-lint/blob/87842ae295c2283d8e02d951781189486a7cc970/lib/ruby-lint/definitions/core/date_time.rb#L7), regardless of whether or not you actually `require 'date-time'`. This tool is a **static** code analysis, so is not aware of the full context in which code is being executed.